# Visual Studio Code debugger not launching browser window or displaying variables

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, vscode-debugger

I'm running a debugging session in Visual Studio Code. I was expecting two things to happen that didn't.

1. For a browser window to open when I launched 'run and debug'.
2. To see a list of variables and their values.

First, I downloaded the Xdebug extension.

[image]

Next, I set a breakpoint on my php file.

[image]

Lastly, I clicked the 'run and debug' button.

I'm hoping someone can offer some advice on where I'm going wrong.

Thanks,
Kyle

Comment: As per your 2nd screenshot, you are using "Listen for Xdebug" configuration. In This mode VSCode does NOT launch anything, it is only listening for incoming debug connections -- useful when you control your Xdebug session via browser extension or trying to debug some CLI script (e.g. run by cron or another event) etc.

Comment: That PHP Debug extension also offers to create "Debug Current Script" type of configuration that executes your current file and listens for debug at the same time. You better check that extension docs to see how to actually launch a browser with specific URL. **P.S.** I'm not really using VSCode myself for PHP debug; but when I've used it it was either "Listen" (and control via browser extension) or that "run CLI script" config.

Comment: You can also use or add a launch.json configuration "Launch Built-in web server" that will start the debug web server (php -S). But the configuration will need some tweaking depending on your code layout.

Answer (score 0):

Check your ports, I recommend using some that you remember, example: default.

I recommend you install php with brew, since with MAMP, XAMP, etc. there is less information in case of error.

```
brew tap shivammathur/php 
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.3
```

This tool gave me a lot of headaches at work, however, on MacOs we have to do a lot of steps.

I recommend that you remember how to install it as it is, because sometimes Visual Studio Code changes the ports when updating.

## Xdebugger installation

These three files are the most important to modify (with nano, vim, etc.)

### php.ini

- Location: `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/php.ini`

```
...
; Local Variables:
; tab-width: 4
; End:
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
```

### 99-xdebug.ini

- Location: `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/99-xdebug.ini`

```
zend_extension = "/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/xdebug.so"
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
```

### Visual Studio Code

#### settings.json

**Important**: xdebug.remote_port, Listen for Xdebug, Launch currently open script are the same port.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for Xdebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```